TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GuildText')
I keep getting this error,
[AntiCrash] | [UncaughtExceptionMonitor_Logs] | [Start] : ===============
Uncaught exception monitor: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GuildText')
Exception origin: uncaughtException
[AntiCrash] | [UncaughtExceptionMonitor_Logs] | [End] : ===============
[AntiCrash] | [UncaughtException_Logs] | [Start] : ===============
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GuildText')
Exception origin: uncaughtException
[AntiCrash] | [UncaughtException_Logs] | [End] : ===============
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { ChannelType } = require('discord.js'); // Ensure you are importing this correctly
const fs = require('fs');
const jailedUsersPath = './src/jailedUsers.json';

// Load jailed users from the file
function loadJailedUsers() {
    return fs.existsSync(jailedUsersPath) ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jailedUsersPath)) : {};
}

function saveJailedUser(userId, guildId, roles) {
    const jailedUsers = loadJailedUsers();
    jailedUsers[userId] = { guildId, roles };
    fs.writeFileSync(jailedUsersPath, JSON.stringify(jailedUsers, null, 4));
}

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('jail')
        .setDescription('Jail a member')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName('user')
                .setDescription('The user to jail')
                .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const member = interaction.options.getMember('user');

        // Ensure the jail system has been set up
        const { jailRole, jailCategory, accessRole } = interaction.client.jailSetup || {};
        if (!jailRole || !jailCategory || !accessRole) {
            return interaction.reply({
                content: 'Jail system is not set up yet. Please run `/jail-setup` first.',
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }

        try {
            // Save current roles
            const memberRoles = member.roles.cache.map(role => role.id);
            saveJailedUser(member.id, interaction.guild.id, memberRoles);

            // Assign jail role to the member
            await member.roles.set([jailRole]);

            // Create the jail channel
            const jailChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
                name: `${member.user.username}-jail`,
                type: ChannelType.message.GuildText, // Ensure you are using the correct type reference
                parent: jailCategory, // Category ID
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                        id: member.id,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: interaction.guild.id,
                        deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], // Deny everyone else
                    },
                    {
                        id: accessRole,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
                        deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'], // Allow access to see but not send messages
                    },
                ],
            });

            await jailChannel.send(`${member} has been jailed. Welcome to jail!`);

            await interaction.reply({ content: `${member.user.username} has been jailed.`, ephemeral: true });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error jailing user:', error);
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'An error occurred while trying to jail the user.', ephemeral: true });
        }
    },
};



I see other examples using ChannelType.GuildText without message in between.  Check this

@James I still get the same error, thank you for the attempt though.

This is happening because ChannelType has no message property. The way to refer to GuildText differs in different versions of discordjs. Check what version of discordjs you have installed from the package.json and use the appropriate property to access the GuildText.



Version
Property
Modified line




v14
ChannelType.GuildText
type: ChannelType.GuildText,


v13
ChannelType.GUILD_TEXT
type: ChannelType.GUILD_TEXT,


v12
ChannelType.text
type: ChannelType.text,



Source:

Differences in API calls in different versions given by @james in the comments
Discord.js ChannelType API reference

